# 2.45GHz microwave coupling to coil

Tags: coil, microwave

I am currently developing a plasma-coating prototype.
As shown in the image, a microwave emits 2.45GHz radiation into an evacuated chamber.
A PET bottle is in chamber, filled with a low pressured gas.
The gas turns into plasma and reacts with the inner surface of the bottle.

To homogenize the plasma reaction with the surface of the bottle, a magnetic field is created inside the chamber (see the two coils inside the chamber).
The resulting magnetic field causes the plasma ions to move on spirals as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror .

The question: Can microwaves escape the shielded chamber through the coil wires? Or is it possible that the coils absorb some microwaves and re-emit radiation outside of the shielded chamber?

[image: visualization]

Comment: Even in a brand-new microwave oven, some RF power escapes. It will be a very low power level and therefore completely safe but not zero. So your question: "Can microwaves escape" Yes they can and they will. Your **real question** is: are the levels low enough to be safe? If there are no holes in the shield larger than a few millimeters then probably the shielding is good enough. Do realize that the EM field inside the shielded case induces RF signals in the coils, can the electronics powering the coils handle that?

Comment: The area of the outer loop compared to n * area of inner loop needs to be shielded to get low levels and probably a CM choke Pi filter

Comment: If you're not sure, you can buy a meter that measures microwave leakage.

Answer (score 0):

EM waves „love“ to follow inductors.

There is a simple school experiment that shows this: Take a perfectly shielded box and put a (FM) radio inside it and listen. You will hear noise. Now penetrate the shield with some cable. You will probably hear sound/music.

You did not tell us the coil signal frequency. If it is far away from 2.45 GHz, you could build a filter.